# How to avoid duplicate font resources?

Tags: fonts, itext

I have some code that uses iTextSharp's `PdfSmartCopy` class to combine multiple smaller PDF files into one big one:

```
FileStream outStream = new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
Document document = new Document();
PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outStream);
document.Open();

foreach (string filename in fileList)
{
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);

   for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++pageNum)
   {
      copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNum));
   }
}

document.Close();
```

When I extract the PDF's resources using `mutool extract`, there are multiple identical copies of each of the fonts it uses:

```
C:\[...]>sha1sum *.cff *.ttf *.png | sort
0d150f99593d385764a1c7096b72448d09af8d72 *JPIOAD+Helvetica-0020.cff
0d150f99593d385764a1c7096b72448d09af8d72 *JPIOAD+Helvetica-0036.cff
0d150f99593d385764a1c7096b72448d09af8d72 *JPIOAD+Helvetica-0049.cff
0d150f99593d385764a1c7096b72448d09af8d72 *JPIOAD+Helvetica-0069.cff
0d150f99593d385764a1c7096b72448d09af8d72 *JPIOAD+Helvetica-0084.cff
0d150f99593d385764a1c7096b72448d09af8d72 *JPIOAD+Helvetica-0099.cff
17a99e597d3ec2cabf567cbfec032972f7e00962 *DXLQZY+LetterGothicW1Bold-0032.ttf
17a99e597d3ec2cabf567cbfec032972f7e00962 *GMYLDU+LetterGothicW1Bold-0014.ttf
17a99e597d3ec2cabf567cbfec032972f7e00962 *MNVLMO+LetterGothicW1Bold-0045.ttf
[etc.]
```

I've examined the *.cff and *.ttf files in FontForge, and it looks like they contain only the subset of characters that are actually used in the document.

Is there a way to make the generated file contain only one copy of the fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText nor iTextSharp can merge subsets of fonts into one single subset. For some fonts, making such a larger subset might be doable, but in some cases, merging different fonts into one will be impossible (in theory, for very large font sets, such as Chinese), in other cases, it will be very difficult (it could mean that entire contents streams need to be rewritten because the character/glyph mapping has changed in the merged font).

In other words: you're asking something that isn't trivial. It's not supported. It's the kind of functionality we'd only consider in the context of paid consultancy.